# Set "New Order Status" to processing instead of pending

Tags: orders, ce-1.9.0.1, status, state

I would like orders with payment type banktransfer and cashondelivery to have the order status "Processing" but it only let me choose "Pending". Magento only allows an order status with state "new" but I would like one from state "processing".

Currently I need to manually change the order status for every order. How can I change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Processing` means an invoice was created. If you want to be able to have the label `Processing` it might work to create a new **status**, name it `processing` but append the **state** `pending`.

However, this might be extremely confusing since it's not very clear which orders where invoiced and which ones weren't

Comment: ok, so I could use something like [this](http://www.atwix.com/magento/auto-invoice-and-custom-order-status-upon-checkout/) to create an invoice and change state for those payments?

Comment: Yes, that would be possible, in that case the order will be put on `processing`